# Error loading ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources

Tags: c#, silverlight, dll, gis

I have a button to print an ArcGIS application map. When I click it I got this exception on my laptop:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources, Version=3.0.0.388,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The strange thing is this exception is not appearing on my college laptop!!!

Please help me get this issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to install the SilverLight API to my laptop.
Thanks